# creating a view in sql-server that allows the entry of new records

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, insert, sql-view

I have a table in sql server 2012 called AccntTemp that has a bunch of columns and an ID column. the person who has to enter data into this table should not be able to see the ID column and a few other columns, but needs to be able to enter data.

So, I need to create a view that allows the entry of new records, but only shows the fields that I want her to see. I know how to create the view so it only shows the fields I want her to see, but I dont know how to make the view so that it will allow the entry of new records.

What do I have to change about my query so that this will work?

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.DataEntry
AS
SELECT code, invno, ven, invdate, amon, accno, amnt, jno, saccno, ckno 
   FROM accnttemp
```

this just created the view, but when I go to the view i cant modify any records or add any new ones. How do I make this happen?

Comment: your view is correct no changes if you want to remove column remove from select statement

Comment: no, i dont want to remove any colums. i want to add rows

Comment: Did you try this?   https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=sql+server+insert+into+view&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=sql+server+insert+into+view&gs_l=hp...0l5.0.0.0.5133...........0.xBoqRXUkm6A

Comment: Are all of the other columns (not included in the view) nullable and/or do they have defaults? If not, what values do you *expect* to be placed in those columns?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "when I go to the view i can't modify"? How are you trying to update the view? An update statement should work just fine. If you are browsing the view in SSMS that is a different story.

Comment: i am using AnySQL maestro and i can not use an insert statement because the person entering data by hand has to enter about 1000 records at a time so she has to do it directly into the table. an insert or update statement is extremely inefficient. and what i mean by "when I go to the view i can't modify" is that when i click thae view, it opens up a table that shows the fields i told it to show. but i cant change anything or add any new entries from the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your view is not already updatable, for some reason (most simple views should be) then you'll have to implement trigger(s) which manipulate the base tables manually.

E.g.

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_DataEntry_I on dbo.DataEntry
instead of insert
as
insert into accnttemp(code, invno, ven, invdate, amon, accno, amnt, jno, saccno, ckno)
SELECT code, invno, ven, invdate, amon, accno, amnt, jno, saccno, ckno 
   FROM inserted
```

With whatever changes are required such that the insert succeeds.

One common reason for a view to not allow `INSERT`s is if there are additional columns in the base table for which neither a `NULL` nor a default value will work. In such a case, you'd have to add those column(s) to the above trigger code and pick or compute appropriate values for them.

---

In case it's not clear, I disagree with TTeeple's answer. The design of SQL is such that, so far as possible, Views and Tables should be indistinguishable. You should be able to replace a table with a view (with the same column definitions, and saving data in appropriate other tables) and not have to make any changes to any client applications that use it.

---

It was, in fact, one of the original [Codd's Rules for Relational Databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules) that views *should* be updatable:

> **Rule 6**: The view updating rule:
>
> All views that are theoretically updatable must be updatable by the system.

Unfortunately, it has since been found that for some views, although a human can implement an update for them, systems are unable to find ways to do so.

Comment: I think there should be better literature on it then.  MSDN has [very little](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800.aspx) on updateable views and the most I could find was on [someone's post](http://www.craigsmullins.com/cnr_0299b.htm) with a nice summary (below the magnifying glass, starting at "When modifying data through a view").  Could you point me to a better place so I don't misinform in the future?

Comment: @TTeeple - avi already linked to technet, but the same is on MSDN for [CREATE VIEW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) "You can modify the data of an underlying base table through a view, as long as the following conditions are true..." It also supports the `CHECK OPTION` feature, similar to what a_horse_with_no_name has commented on below your answer. That entire feature only makes sense when you're using updatable views.

Comment: so when i run this script that creates the trigger, how will it look to the person entering the data? @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score -1):

There is something in the documentation. Check this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

> Updatable Views
>
> You can modify the data of an underlying base table through a view, as
>   long as the following conditions are true:
>
> Any modifications, including UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements,
>   must reference columns from only one base table.
>
> The columns being modified in the view must directly reference the
>   underlying data in the table columns. The columns cannot be derived in
>   any other way, such as through the following:
>
> An aggregate function: AVG, COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX, GROUPING, STDEV,
>   STDEVP, VAR, and VARP.
>
> A computation. The column cannot be computed from an expression that
>   uses other columns. Columns that are formed by using the set operators
>   UNION, UNION ALL, CROSSJOIN, EXCEPT, and INTERSECT amount to a
>   computation and are also not updatable.
>
> The columns being modified are not affected by GROUP BY, HAVING, or
>   DISTINCT clauses.
>
> TOP is not used anywhere in the select_statement of the view
>   together with the WITH CHECK OPTION clause.

Comment: yeah my view fits that criteria but i still cant update while in the view

Comment: on your queries are you referencing columns from only one base table?

Comment: my queries arent used to add data to tables. all that is done through the table view

Answer (score -2):

Views SHOULD NOT allow insertion of data, only reading.  What you are looking to do is possible through triggers but it is not advisable.

You are looking for a function or stored procedure.

Updating answer so I don't spam comments:

That is why you give them a stored procedure that accepts parameters.  They know nothing of the underlying logic, they just know that this stored procedure puts the parameters they supply into the table they need.  They check the view and their new data is there now.

It is generally bad practice since you can only accomplish it through the use of triggers, which can have some nasty side effects.  So if done correctly and everything is accounted for (both present and future), then go ahead.  The user has to have `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` permissions on the base table anyway.

Comment: how would i add a trigger to the view? my superior insists that the data entry is done through a view

Comment: You can read up on [them here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521.aspx) but I don't have any experience in doing this as it is bad practice.  I would go back to your superior and question why he thinks it needs to be done this way.

Comment: its because the columns that are not supposed to be seen by the data entry person contain information she is not authorized to see. may i ask why it is bad practice?

Comment: By default, simple views are updatable with no need for triggers. And the users don't need permissions on the base tables.

Comment: Why shouldn't views not allow inserts? Is this something that is specific to SQL Server? Some limitation? In Oracle an Postgres it's not that unusual to allow inserts through views (because people are only allowed to _access_ the data through view as well). Postgres even supports the `with check` option to prevent adding rows that wouldn't be returned by the view.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - SQL Server also has [CHECK OPTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) for the same functionality.